# what is the difference between var createControl = function (attribute){ ...} $.fn.createControl = function (attribute) { .. }

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

What is the difference between

```
var createControl = function (attribute){ ...}
```

**and**

```
$.fn.createControl = function (attribute) { .. }
```

in jQuery. What is the advantage of changing a function from $.fn.createControl to var createControl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var foo = function (param) { ... }
```

Assigns a function to `foo`.

```
$.fn.foo = function (param) { ... }
```

Extends the prototype of jQuery with `foo`. `fn` is just a shortcut to `prototype` and `$` is a shortcut for `jQuery`. You could write the same thing as:

```
jQuery.prototype.foo = function (param) { ... }
```

The difference is that the former is just a variable within a certain scope, invisible outside of it. The later is a method extending the jQuery global object, thus making the variable accessible from anywhere since the jQuery object is attached to `window`, is global.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the syntax for writing jQuery plugins, so you can call your custom plugins like so:

```
$(selector).createControl();
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

That way, your `createControl()` can tell which elements it is being called upon. If you are doing `var createControl`, you need to either pass in the selector to the function, or hard code it within the function.

Answer (score 0):

the use of `$.fn.createControl = function() {}` allows for the use of plugins. for instance, if someone wants to make a plugin for something and want to let the user decide what element he wants the plugin to be used for the person can just do `$('#element').createControl();`

just doing `var createControl = function() {}` just creates a function and its only use is to be called separately such as `createControl();` without any selector element in front of it.